# NSCompoundPredicate does not work for more than one predicate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Here are my predicates:

```
1) category.enabled == 1 AND (author CONTAINS[c] "John" OR city CONTAINS[c] "John" OR state CONTAINS[c] "John")

2) category.enabled == 1 AND (author CONTAINS[c] "dallas" OR city CONTAINS[c] "dallas" OR state CONTAINS[c] "dallas")

3) category.enabled == 1 AND ((author CONTAINS[c] "John" OR city CONTAINS[c] "John" OR state CONTAINS[c] "John") OR (author CONTAINS[c] "dallas" OR city CONTAINS[c] "dallas" OR state CONTAINS[c] "dallas"))
```

Here is code how it is constructed:

```
-(void)findString:(NSString *)string {
    
    if (!string) {
        string = @"";
    }
    NSMutableArray *predicatesArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSArray *searchQueriesArray = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
    NSPredicate *categoryPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"category.enabled == %@",[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
    for(NSString *query in searchQueriesArray){
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"author CONTAINS[cd] %@ OR city CONTAINS[cd] %@ OR state CONTAINS[cd] %@", query, query, query];
        [predicatesArray addObject:predicate];
    }
    NSPredicate *fieldsSearchPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:predicatesArray];
    NSArray *searchPredicatesArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:categoryPredicate,fieldsSearchPredicate, nil];
    NSPredicate *searchPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:searchPredicatesArray];
    self.tracks = [Track findAllSortedBy:@"name" ascending:YES withPredicate:searchPredicate];
    
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

the 1) predicate was constructed with `string = "John";`
the 2) with string = `"dallas";`
the 3) with `string = "John dallas"`

So problem is: searching with 1) or with 2) predicate returns results, but with 3) does not return any results.

Comment: Are you sure that you do not need quotation marks around your `%@` symbols in the format string? I am not sure that it is going to do anything, but could you try this format instead: `@"author CONTAINS[cd] \"%@\" OR city CONTAINS[cd] \"%@\" OR state CONTAINS[cd] \"%@\"`?